# Receive Type Error when removing this line of code

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, typeerror

I found this code on [text](https://towardsdatascience.com/two-pointer-approach-python-code-f3986b602640) and was attempting to understand each line while trying to understand Two Pointers concept.

```
def sortedSquares(nums):
    n = len(nums)
    start, end = 0, n -1 ## This is where I am confused, why is 'n - 1' necessary
    res = [0]*n
    idx = n-1

while end > -1 and idx >-1:
    if abs(nums[start]) > abs(nums[end]):
        res[idx] = nums[start] * nums[start]
        start +=1
    else:
        res[idx] = nums[end] * nums[end]
        end -= 1
    idx -= 1

return res

print(sortedSquares([-4,-3,0,1,10]))
```

This program returns ' TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object ' when you removed the comment.

Can anybody explain what that n - 1 is actually used for to the computer.

I removed the n - 1 as it doesn't look necessary, but it blatantly is in the Console.

Comment: "when you removed the comment." you mean just removing ## symbols ?